# How to change the color of NSSplitView's divider on nib?

Tags: cocoa, swift, nssplitview

I want to change the color of `NSSplitView`'s `dividerColor` in my Cocoa app, but when I typed in the following code, the error `Cannot assign to the result of this expression` occurred.

```
splitView.dividerColor = NSColor.redColor()
```

I think this is because `.dividerColor` is a read-only property and thus you cannot overwrite the color from within code if you instantiate it from nib.

However, I cannot find any such preferences to change the color in Xcode's Inspector on the `NSSplitView`. So how can I change the color of the divider?

Note that I don't use `NSSplitViewController`; I use `NSSplitView` on top of the `NSViewController`.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're happy to stick to using the *Thin Divider* style, you can change the color of the splitview's divider by using a subclass of `NSSplitView`, and overriding the `dividerColor` property:

```
class MySplitView: NSSplitView {

    override var dividerColor: NSColor {
        return NSColor.redColor()
    }

}
```

Comment: That might be able to be simplified into just `override var dividerColor: NSColor{ return NSColor.redColor() }`, because the `get` is implied.

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise the ``get`` could be dropped. Have edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Still not sure whether this passes Apple's review, but I would try.

Comment: If by *review* you mean the process Apple puts an app through before clearing it for the App Store, I'd be surprised if they would fail you simply for changing the divider color of a split-view. After all, they've provided explicit API to allow you to do it!